# Responsive Background Image w/ Full Width Inside Div Container

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, background-image

I would like to create a background image inside a container that is about halfway down on the page.  The height would maybe be 20%-30% of the screen height.  Do I need to create more than one image and use CSS Media question to display one image and hide all the other images for each resolution range?  Or, is there an easier way to make the image scale automatically.    Does it help if the image is in vector format?

Comment: Can you share the current code.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that shows something very close to what I want. http://jsfiddle.net/natetg/75x0hvf1/  I just want the image to show up halfway down on the screen instead of at the top.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the image to always cover the div, you can use CSS3's new `background-size` values:

```
background-size: cover | contain;
```

#### cover

With cover, the image will always fill the whole container no matter the size, the browser will adjust the image, and the image might get cropped.

#### contain

The whole image will be always visible, i.e if the container gets smaller than the image, image is scaled down to fit the container, this way, it's normal to see empty spaces in container.